# Vue: Accessing data from an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have an issue where I want to retreive data from a child component, but the parent needs to use that data, *before* the child is mounted.

My parent looks like this

```
<template>
    <component :is="childComp" @mounted="setData"/>
</template>
<script>
    data : {
        childComp : null,
        importantData : null
    },
    methods : {
        addComponent : function() {
            this.prepareToAdd(this.importantData);
            this.childComp = "componentA"; //sometimes will be other component
        },
        setData : function(value) {
            this.importantData = value;
        },
        prepareToAdd : function(importantData){
            //something that has to be run before childComp can be mounted.
        }
    }
</script>
```

My child (or rather, all the potential children) would contain something like this:

```
<script>
    data : {
        importantData : 'ABC',
    },
    created: function() {
        this.$emit('mounted', this.importantData);
    },
</script>
```

This clearly doesn't work - `importantData` is set when the childComponent is mounted, but `prepareToAdd` needs that data first.

Is there another way of reaching in to the child component and accessing its data, before it is mounted?

Comment: Why delegate the responsibility for retrieving that data to the child component rather than the parent?

Comment: Can you describe a little more clearly what the requirement is? Is the parent setting up something in its own state? Something that will be passed to the child as a prop? Something in the DOM? Why does it need to be run before the child mounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) to store your important data and have it available in `beforeCreate`. You can also use it to initialize a `data` item, and you can emit `data` items in `created` (you don't have to initialize from `$options` to emit in `created`, I'm just pointing out two things that can be done). The `$options` value is, itself, reactive (to my surprise) and can be used like any `data` item, with the added benefit that it is available before other `data` items.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    doStuff(val) {
      console.log("Got", val);
    }
  },
  components: {
    theChild: {
      template: '<div>Values are {{$options.importantData}} and {{otherData}}</div>',
      importantData: 'abc',
      data() {
        return {
          otherData: this.$options.importantData
        };
      },
      beforeCreate() {
        this.$emit('before-create', this.$options.importantData);
      },
      created() {
        this.$emit('on-created', this.otherData + ' again');
        // It's reactive?!?!?
        this.$options.importantData = 'changed';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <the-child @before-create="doStuff" @on-created="doStuff"></the-child>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks, this is just what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

My bad :(

We cannot get the data inside beforeCreated() hook.

<strike>Use the beforeCreate() hook instead of created() hook:</strike>

```
beforeCreate: function() {
   this.$emit('mounted', this.importantData);
},
```

We can use a watcher or computed option, so now your parent component would look:

```
data: {
  childComp: null,
  importantData: null,
  isDataSet: false
 },
 methods: {
  addComponent: function() {
   this.prepareToAdd(this.importantData);
   this.childComp = "componentA"; //sometimes will be other component
  },
  setData: function(value) {
   this.importantData = value;
   this.isDataSet = true;
  },
  prepareToAdd: function(importantData) {
   //something that has to be run before childComp can be mounted.
  }
 },
 watch: {
  isDataSet: function(newValue, oldValue) {
   if (newValue) {
    this.addComponent();
   }
  }
 }
```

I would suggest to use computed method as it caches the results. Use watcher when you have to perform asynchronous code.

Comment: Wouldn't this have the same issue - `importantData` is set when the `childComponent` is mounted

Comment: `importantData` is set when the child emits a `mounted` event. That is being done in the child's `beforeCreate` hook.

Comment: I thought `data` in the child is not initialized until the `create` hook? Take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/z26rrm7xwl), `setData` gets `null` when using `beforeCreate`

Comment: @sklingler93 You're right, beforeCreate hook is not the way.... updated my answer.